# Does "was going to try it out in the morning" mean tomorrow morning the first time?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the book The Great Gatsby on page forty there is a sentence:
"Evidently he lived in this vicinity, for he told me that he has just bought a hydroplane, and was going to try it out in the morning."
Does "was going to try it out in the morning" mean tomorrow morning the first time or he has been trying it more morning til now and tomorrow he will continue with trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the former. Tomorrow morning will be the first time that he tries using the hydroplane.

Typically if someone wants to express that the next morning *isn't* the first time, they'll add again, or keep. For example:

```
We'll try again in the morning.

We'll keep trying tomorrow morning.
```

Answer (score 1):

*To try something out* is to use it to see if it works well, or what it is like. You usually try out new things, things that you don't know how they function.

> Lanny is trying out her new bicycle.
>
> She knew I wanted to try the boat out at the weekend.
>
> The school hopes to try out the system in September.

*In the morning* refers to either *tomorrow morning* or *this morning*. As put @Jason Bassford it, it depends when it was said and it usually signifies ***the upcoming morning***.

Comment: Does "the upcoming morning" mean the first time?

Comment: @b2ok no, but "try out" implies it